# Android Twitter4J newest and most popular Tweets

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

**I would like to get the newest and most popular tweets with the hashtag "proverbs" using Twitter4J**, but when I try to do it, the results I get are not the newest and most popular (I know that because I compared them with the results I got while searching the same hashtag on twitter and they are not the same). Here is my code:

```
public class Wisdom extends SherlockActivity {
Context mContext;
Twitter mTwitter;
ListView mListView;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_hastag_wisdom);
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
mContext = getApplicationContext();
mTwitter = getTwitter();

StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
        .permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
showTweetsAbout("#proverbs");

}

 private Twitter getTwitter() {
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setOAuthConsumerKey(xxxxxxx);
cb.setOAuthConsumerSecret(xxxxxxx);
cb.setOAuthAccessToken(xxxxxxx);
cb.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(xxxxxxx);
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
return twitter;
} 

private void showTweetsAbout(String queryString) {
ArrayList<String> tweetsArray = new ArrayList<String>();

Twitter twitter = mTwitter;
Query query = new Query(queryString);
query.setResultType(Query.MIXED);
query.setCount(30);
QueryResult result;

try {
    result = twitter.search(query);

    for (Status tweet : result.getTweets()) {
        Log.d("Wisdom", tweet.getUser() + ":" + tweet.getText());
        tweetsArray.add(tweet.getText());
        for (URLEntity urle : tweet.getURLEntities()) {
            System.out.println(urle.getDisplayURL());
        }
    }
} catch (TwitterException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ArrayAdapter<String> tweetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.row, tweetsArray);

mListView.setAdapter(tweetsAdapter);
}
}
```

*Code would also be greatly appreciated swell as an explanation, thanks.*

Answer (score -1):

Despite the fact that you're doing network operation on main thread (!!) Try to specifiy in query result untill date

```
query.setUntill(date);
```

As a date set current time, it returns tweets generated before given date.

Another question is how much results from twitter4j differ from tweets on site ? It's possible that in meantime between doing a query in mobile app and querying website a few new tweets with given hashtag came up.